# How do I display a list of Wi-Fi connections using netsh

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

Using command `netsh wlan show profiles` through a command prompt shows a list of all the all Wi-Fi available at that time to which my computer can connect.

But it only shows one Wi-Fi which is I am using whereas when I click the network and sharing center icon on right side of status bar it shows various Wi-Fi both secured and unsecured to which my computer can connect.

How can I display the other wireless connections?

Comment: is the command available in `cygwin`?

Answer (score 13):

#### How can I display the other wireless connections?

> command `netsh wlan show profiles` through command prompt shows list of all the all Wi-Fi available at that time to which my computer can connect.

The above command shows only those connections which have **profiles**.

- They are connections you have previously connected to and have saved configurations.
- It will always show your **current** connection (if you are using wireless).
- These connections may not be available from your current location.

To list all **available** connections you need to use a different `netsh` command:

```
netsh wlan show networks
```

- These connections are available at your current location.
- You must be disconnected from all wireless networks before running this command.

Example output (names have been obscured):

```
f:\test>netsh wlan show networks

Interface name : Wireless Network Connection
There are 22 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : SKYXXXXX
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP

SSID 2 : SKYXXXXX
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP

SSID 3 : XXXXX
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP

SSID 4 : BTOpenzoneXXX
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : Open
    Encryption              : None

...
```

---

#### Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)

> **show networks**
>
> Displays a list of wireless networks that are visible on the computer.
>
> Syntax
>
> `show networks [[interface=]InterfaceName] [[mode=]{ssid|bssid}]`
>
> ...
>
> **show profiles**
>
> Displays a list of wireless profiles that are configured on the
> computer.
>
> Syntax
>
> `show profiles [[name=]ProfileName] [[interface=]InterfaceName] [[key=clear]`

Source - [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: This is especially good, now that Windows 8+ stopped displaying additional network information (encryption type etc) from the built-in GUI, like was the case in Windows 7 and older by hovering the mouse above the network names.

Comment: I put "netsh wlan show networks" and get 0 networks while I'm actually using one of them to write this post. Why is that?

Comment: @Peter.k Try disconnect before run this command.

Comment: **This solution does not work for me on Windows 10. Shows only one network, but I have more than twenty Wi-Fi networks.**

Comment: @jackdaw did you disconnect from your current wireless network before running this command?

Comment: @music2myear During the tests, the computer connected to the current network all the time for few hours.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Also, you can tell your computer to disconnect and disable automatic connection, which is what you must do in order to run the command, as others here have noted.

Comment: **`netsh` garbles Unicode SSIDs.** For the two different SSIDs “``” and “`F09FA78A`,” `netsh wlan show networks` shows `SSID 3 : F09FA78A … SSID 4 : F09FA78A`.

Answer (score 0):

- To list all Wi-Fi networks that are available (in range) on the command line, use:

```bat
netsh wlan show networks
```

**Obs.:** This command shows that the Wi-Fi network is currently connected, for a list of all available networks, disconnect your current network first.

---

- For a listing of **`SSID [Number] : [Name]`** only:

```bat
netsh wlan show networks|find "SSID"
```

---

- For a listing of **`[Names]`** only:

```bat
for /f "tokens=2*delims=: " %i in ('netsh wlan show networks^|find "SSID"')do @echo\%j
```